# Facebook - open profile by app_scoped_user_id

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a list of facebook users' app_scoped_user_id, which was what is stored in our database and returned by our app when the app requests permission to view the profile.

I can open the profile by going to [http://facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/(id)](http://facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/%28id%29).

How can I get an iOS app to open the native facebook app and view the profile by ID?

fb://profile/(id) doesn't work, as that page wants the "Facebook ID", which isn't the app_scoped_id.

What do I do here? I don't understand why this is not possible. If I open facebook.com/(app_scoped_id) in browser it works. If I open that page as a "link in textview" in the app, it opens a blank event page (no clue why it goes to events?). If I open facebook.com/events/valideventID - it opens the correct event.

I just want to open the user's facebook profile in the app based on his/her app scoped ID.

Comment: I would file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. It has something to do with the separation of app IDs and user IDs after Graph V.2, but I can't figure out how to work around this problem - it seems a bit silly as this does in no way prevent me from viewing anyone's profiles. All it does it makes it less convenient.

Comment: For me it sounds like a bug that you can't link to a profile in the Facebook app using an app scoped user id

Comment: Possibly. I worked around it by just letting the mobile browser take over. If I open the link http://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/(id) it will just jump to Safari and show the user. That's sufficient for the use I required but of course not an answer or a solution to the bug - if it is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the bug report on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332195860270199 opening the Facebook profile with fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=%@ is not supported.

You will have to open the Facebook profile within Safari (http://facebook.com/%@). It's annoying but works as a workaround ...

Maybe you could comment under the bug report that you need this feature like I did.

Instead of using Safari you could also use an in app web browser. This it what I'll try.

Comment: I just added an in app web browser from Sam Vermette: https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController. It works flawless an was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: NSString *fbProfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://facebook.com/%@", profileId];  
SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = 
[[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:fbProfile];
  [self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];