# Not able to open particular user profile page in native iOS Facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, swift4

This might be duplicate question but from other's posted answer am not getting any solution that's why i am posting.

I am working on one app which is related to social networks. I want to open particular user's profile in facebook native app. I tried many other solutions posted by others, but nothing is working for me at all. I refered https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/332195860270199/ this link 
,They have stopped this things it seems.

Application's web part is in ember.js so we are rendering webview to login into all social networks.

In response i am getting below link https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/YXNpZADpBWExxxxxxxxxxUVzloZAzVPSWc0TVhBNnZAYcWxxxxxxxxxxxxxWpWTm51bDNOblxxxxxxxxxxxZAYnRyM0FXbmlxxxxxxxxxxAeTYxTGxxxxxxxxxxTTE1TcVdExxxxxxxxxxXlFZAGxxxxxxxxxxMDNIRS0ycU96/

I am trying to open user's profile using

```
fb://facewebmodal/f?href=\(above link)
```

this link working fine for browser and android but not opening profile in native iOS facebook app.

I tried many other solutions also, Like

1. `fb://profile?href=\(above link)  //Opening My profile not particular user`
2. `fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id/\(above link) . //opening my profile`
3. `fb://profile/1000xxxxxxx4469 // this is working as expected but don't know how to get this id 1000xxxxxxx4469`. I generated this id from https://findmyfbid.com/
4. I checked this link [Facebook - open profile by app_scoped_user_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191532/facebook-open-profile-by-app-scoped-user-id), But that is 2014 old post and not useful for me.

So, How to open particular user's profile in facebook native app using swift4?

I really need solution for this. any help will be appreciated

Comment: Yeah, I got the same issue. It' working for web browser but not working for a native Facebook app.

Comment: As i didn't get any response for this question, i did some workaround . That is, instead of opening profile page in native facebook app am rendering app_scoped_user_id url within app using webkit. This is temporary solution. Still i am waiting for some solution.

Comment: Reference URL: 
https://medium.com/@shrawan25.sharma/urgent-facebook-sdk-app-update-to-retain-permission-access-a256b76e5bd5

Comment: I too have the same issue. But my case is very simple which will have few users FB profile links. My app will simply navigate to native FB app OR safari to load them by extracting the username from the URL based on the native FB availability in device. Profile is loading fine when it navigates to mobile's safari from my application but when it navigates to native Facebook, it is simply showing my profile instead of the desired user's profile page. My app doesn't require any FB SDK since I'm not fetching any logged in user's profile. Can you please suggest with the solution if you have any?